# Query Cloudant NoSQL database with respect to time intervals

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, nosql

I'am working on Cloudant NoSQL database, the data is received every 15 seconds, so in every 5 mins there will be 20 documents on the database.

I need to get documents which have a difference in timestamp of five minutes for example, Document with time stamp:`"2017-03-14 T 18:21:58"` and
Document with time stamp:`"2017-03-14 T 18:26:58"` and so on...

Sample document:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make a view keyed on the timestamp. I interpret your question as "get all 20 documents sharing a particular timestamp". If that's the case you can get away with not parsing the timestamp:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc && doc.timestamp) {
        emit(doc.timestamp, 1)
    }
}
```

You can now query the view:

```
% curl 'https://USER:PASS@ACCOUNT.cloudant.com/DATABASE/_design/DDOC/view/VIEWNAME?key=TIMESTAMP&include_docs=true&limit=20'
```

Substitute the uppercase bits to the relevant names and parameters for your system.

If you need finer granularity for your query (time series style), there is an old-but-useful blog from one of the Cloudant founders on the topic here: https://cloudant.com/blog/mapreduce-from-the-basics-to-the-actually-useful/